# Storing large result sets in cache/redis with laravel 5

Tags: php, api, caching, laravel-5, redis

I'm caching some eloquent/api call results in redis with the cache driver in laravel.

I'm getting a +/- 4000 rows result with each 20 something keys. It's a fairly large json string. Right now I'm tossing that straight to the cache driver which is probably not the best way to do this. It's still faster then doing the api call every time. But loading it from cache is still taking like 5-6 seconds. Looking in the network tab the result is about 12 mb.

On my local machine this works fine. On my heroku environment redis maxes out on memory usage.

So question is, what would be a good way to store this in redis with the caching driver?

Answer (score 3):

Since the data is very large, you should use a compression lib, e.g. `zlib`, to compress the data before saving to Redis. That would reduce the size of data stored in Redis. It would also reduce the network latency when you write to/read from Redis.